# Hibernate-NamedSqlQuery UserType as a ReturnType

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hibernate-mapping, usertype

I've got a mapped class in Hibernate that contains a named sql-query that calculates the minimum of an integer for some search-parameters. The actual query is quite complex (so I can neither write it as a Criteria nor as an HQL in my Hibernate-version).

The return type in the database is an integer but I've got an Usertype that maps that integer to a date (db-schema modification is also not possible in my case).

The question is: how to specify a return type for my named query that is resolved via a Custom-UserType.

I tried the following. My UserType is

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <typedef class="com.package.MyUserType" name="MyUserType"/>
    <class>...</class>
    <sql-query name="queryName">
        <return-scalar column="alpha" type="MyUserType"/>
        select min(myColumn) as alpha from Table01 where attribute=:param
    </sql-query>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

But executing that named query results in

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: could not determine type null
```

But `MyUserType` is working fine inside my class-mapping.

**edit:**

I just found out that it is working fine if I use `com.package.MyUserType` as type. So the problem seems to be that my typedef is not working properly in my sql-query. In my class it is working fine. (Note the typedef-line in the hibernate-mapping shown above)

Hibernate-version I have to use: 3.2.7.ga

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as stated in my edit:

```
<return-scalar column="alpha" type="com.package.MyUserType"/>
```

is working fine. The typedef definition is not working for some reason. I didnt find any bug-report like that for my hibernate-version.